# Using jquery to get google "results 1-100 of about" ??? "for..." value

Tags: php, parsing, jquery

I have a question.

How could I get the data from a google search response? 
I.e.:Results 1 - 100 of about **230,533,709** for blogs. (0.25 seconds)

I want to get the value **230,533,709**.

I use php to get the html response from the url. 
I.e.: http://blogsearch.google.com/blogsearch?hl=en&ie=UTF-8&q=blogs&btnG=Search+Blogs

I use ajax to get the code from php:

```
$.ajax({
 url: "urlToPhp",
 type: "GET",
 dataType: "html",
 data: $('#form').serialize(),
 beforeSend: function(){}, 
 success: function(html) {
           ->what to do with html to get the value 230,533,709???
$('#results').html(test).show('slow');
}
});
```

Please help. I don't know how to do this.
Regards!

---

It still doesn't work. Could you please paste the complete code how you get the content and then parse the results value?

I tried this piece of code and doesn't work:

```
$("#results").load("http://blogsearch.google.com/blogsearch?hl=en&ie=UTF-8&q=blogs&btnG=Search+Blogs", function(data){
  alert(data); <- returns empty string
  alert($(data).text()); <-returns null
  alert($(data).find('b:eq(3)')); <- returns "[object Object]"
});
```

Why data is not the downloaded content. What means [object Object]?

Thank for your help.

Regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using a selector (not tested, might need top adjust the selector):

```
var count = $(html).find('table.ttt td.rsb b:nth-child(2)').html();
```

---

UPDATE:

adjust the selector:

```
var count = $(html).find('b:eq(3)').html();
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this (basedon Darin's answer):

```
$('table.ttt td.rsb b:nth-child(3)').html();
```

I got `261,022,603`

Comment: I tried 

var count = $(html).find('table.ttt td.rsb b:nth-child(3)').html();

and still getting NULL! 

Don't know what's the problem?

Comment: @o.k.w could you please paste the complete ajax code to see how you have got the result?

Comment: @Jooj: Darin's answer of `find('b:eq(3)')` works, you should try that. This answer of mine tried without ajax fetching so not really ideal for you.

Answer (score 0):

good idea is -

1. Take all html
2. Parse in php $.post() with preg_match()
3. Got result

Not use jquery against page from google.